# How to measure the size of a document in Firestore programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way we can measure the size of a Firestore document? For example:

```
docId.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task .isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task .getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            double size = document.getSize(); // Does not exist
        }
    }
});
```

I've seen [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size), but I need to get it programmatically. I need to get the size of a document in Kb. Is this even possbile?

Comment: There is no provided implementation.  You can write your own algorithm based on what you read in the documentation.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok, thank you.